# how to execute eclipse shortcut from keyboard?

Tags: eclipse

I saw eclipse shortcut to run a junit test is described like this:

Alt+Shift+D, P

But i don't understand how to do it? I press Alt then Shift then D then P but it doesn't work. How to actually do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` sign means "all at the same time". The `,` sign means "and then". So, you press `Alt`, `Shift` and `D` at the same time, release them all, and then press `P`.

Comment: What i missed is released them. So thanks for clarifying it. For some reason it is not clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hold down all of them at once.**

D,P indicates you press

`Alt+Shift+D` then `P`